# Shell Script command output stream overwriting old lines

Tags: shell

I have a shell script that calls a command (`sudo apt-get update`). The current status is displayed in the terminal, but the older lines obviously move upwards. What I want to achieve is that the X recent lines are displayed and as a new line appears an old one is deleted. This means the output should always only occupy X lines.

I tried tail and sed but couldn't achieve the wanted result.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with allowing the output to scroll as it was intended to?

Comment: There are other things in the script that i want to keep on the screen

Comment: Then you need ncurses. I've seen something like that in the builder for Armbian, where the apt-get output was supposed to be limited to a box in part of the terminal, but the feature was actually quite broken when I tried it, which only goes to demonstrate how very *not the right thing to do* it is.

Comment: The right thing to do is decide you need a real UI, and your project is not just a terminal application anymore, and use wxPython or something to get a real UI.

Comment: I feared that type of answer but I guess you are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you, like myself, is running the terminal session within `tmux`, then you can ask `tmux` to split the window and run another command in the new pane:

```
$ tmux split-window "sudo apt-get update"
```

The newly created pane will close as soon as the command has finished, so you may want to add a `read` afterwards (which will stall until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
$ tmux split-window "sudo apt-get update; read"
```

You can read more about the `split-window` command in the `tmux` manual, but I'll just mention that if you add `-l`*`N`*, e.g. `tmux split-window -l 5 ...`, then you'll get a new pane with *N* rows (five in this example).